# Mysql:Combine select queries from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I would like to combine different queries into one and group by field. When I execute the queries separatly I get the results required but I cannot combine them.I thought union or union all should combine them.

Below is the query.

```
(select cmb_region, count(*) as count1 
 from leases 
 where txt_contr_end <= CURDATE() 
 group by cmb_region) 
union 
(select cmb_region, count(*) as count2 
 from leases 
 where txt_contr_end >= CURDATE() 
 group by cmb_region);
```

This is the results I get:

```
+------------+--------+
| cmb_region | count1 |
+------------+--------+
| Central    |    648 |
| NGA        |    647 |
| NULL       |    140 |
| SGS        |      1 |
| Central    |    855 |
| NGA        |    855 |
| NULL       |      5 |
+------------+--------+
```

Everything is name the same. THe results of count two are not there.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you please share table structure and output you want

Comment: I tried to make it concise.

Comment: The results of count two ***are*** there...  In the place you put them...  Under the `count1` column...

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 different columns like this.

```
(select cmb_region, count(*) as count1, 0 as count2 
 from leases 
 where txt_contr_end <= CURDATE() 
 group by cmb_region) 
union 
(select cmb_region, 0 as count1, count(*) as count2 
 from leases 
 where txt_contr_end >= CURDATE() 
 group by cmb_region);
```

OR if you need them in the same row

```
 select cmb_region, 
        sum(CASE WHEN txt_contr_end <= CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count1,
        sum(CASE WHEN txt_contr_end >= CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count2 
 from leases 
 group by cmb_region
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 separate columns?

Comment: They represent different things i.e count 1 is expired and count2 is not expired.

Comment: Me? I don't need columns) Looks like the author need 2 different columns. At least I understand that from the column names. If just one column is necessary it could be calculated in one

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html -UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned

Comment: @StanislavL, the second query works but do not understand why do you have the last where clause. If I remove it I get +------------+--------+--------+
| cmb_region | count1 | count2 |
+------------+--------+--------+
| Central    |    648 |    855 |
| NGA        |    647 |    855 |
| NULL       |    140 |      5 |
| SGS        |      1 |      0 |
+------------+--------+--------+

Comment: @Jones you are right. Left it by mistake copy/paste